# Is "the hole where the tooth had been" acceptable

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

> The hole **where the tooth had been** was now filled with cotton
> ( a dentist had just extracted the tooth.)

I wrote the sentence, but I hesitated using the relative clause, because I suddenly realized it would suggest the tooth had been in a hole,  which is apparently not true -  there wasn't a hole before the extraction.

Do you native speakers feel the sentence acceptable?

Comment: The sentence is clear, standard English.  Better still, it is brief and vivid.

Comment: @user405662 Actually, it's a preposition ("in the place").

Comment: I don't see any real ambiguity here. It's clear that extracting the tooth left a hole where the tooth had been.

Comment: The hole where a tooth goes is called a socket.

Comment: ...which is a type of hole.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary definitions do not add much to common understanding so I give none. More generally:

A hole is a recognisable volume (or area) in some material where we might (as a possibility) expect there to be that material. Thus we talk of a hole that needs to be filled in the road or of a hole that needs to be patched in a sheet. Once it exists it does not disappear: it can only be filled and there is always a difference, no matter how small, between the filling and the surrounding. There are small differences in the composition of the asphalt or cloth, discontinuities at the join and so forth. It is an adjectivally modified hole: a filled hole, a patched hole.

Not all holes require filling: a hole in a wall may be a doorway; a hole in the body may be the mouth or the anus.

Some holes are transient; the hole we blow in the surface of water fills and vanishes when we stop blowing and cannot be detected (does not exist) thereafter.

So what sort of hole is the one in your jaw? I suggest that it is an adjectivally modified hole - a filled hole. It is a hole that was once occupied by a tooth and is now filled with cotton wool. The volume of the hole was always distinguishable from, and defined by, the surrounding bone. It was filled by tooth and is now filled by wool.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the clause talking about the hole uses simple past and the clause starting with "where" uses pluperfect, and that simple past comes after pluperfect in tense sequencing, it seems pretty clear that the hole is only referred to as existing after the extraction. Whether it existed before the extraction is irrelevant. Likewise, discussion about what makes up a hole is also irrelevant. There is clearly a hole in the post-extraction timeline.